Why can Rename-Item be piped directly to Get-ChildItem?
To use Powershell to execute a program against all files in a directory, the command should be:
Get-ChildItem -File | Foreach {myprog $_.fullname}

However, I can use Rename-Item directly without Foreach:
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -newname 'a' -whatif

Why is that?

PowerShell's provider cmdlets decorate their output items - such as System.IO.FileInfo / System.IO.DirectoryInfo as emitted by Get-ChildItem - with provider-specific properties, notably including .PSPath, which contains the full, native path to the item, prefixed with the provider name. On receiving such items via the pipeline, provider cmdlets bind them by property name to their -LiteralPath parameter, whose alias is -PSPath. See the linked duplicate for details.

PS> Get-Help Rename-Item -Parameter LiteralPath

-LiteralPath <string>

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    Named
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName)
    Parameter set name           ByLiteralPath
    Aliases                      PSPath
    Dynamic?                     false

What should be taken from this snippet are lines:
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName)
    Aliases                      PSPath

If an Object is piped to Rename-Item and has a property named LiteralPath or PSPath, the value of that property will be input to Rename-Item as an argument bound to the LiteralPath parameter.
For instance, Get-ChildItem returns objects that have a Property named PSPath.
